# Crash when set the module in the RealmConfiguration

Tags: java, android, eclipse, realm

Here's my Module

```
@RealmModule(classes = { 
    Episode.class,
    Item.class,
    Stage.class,
    StageInfo.class,
    UserAttr.class,
    UserInfo.class,
    SyncTime.class
})
public class UserModule
{
}
```

And this is my `RealmConfiguration`

```
config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(_activity)
                .name("user.realm")
                .setModules(new UserModule())
                .schemaVersion(2)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
```

Finally, this is what I get after my app crashes.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.realm.UserModuleMediator
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.realm.UserModuleMediator" on path:
```

And when I export JAR (of Realm Project in Eclipse), I don't see any included `io.realm.UserModuleMediator` or something.
There are only `DefaultRealmModule.java` and `DefaultRealmMuduleMediator.java`.

Eclipse project is exported as JAR and I use it for native plugin for Unity. And I export resources in `src` & `.apt_generated`

Comment: Does the application work from within Eclipse or only when using the exported bundle? How do you create the bundle? Please provide more details in your question.

Comment: Also I'm using GSON for an adapter for Realm models.

Comment: Have you checked if `UserModuleMediator` is in the `.apt_generated` folder? If yes, it sounds like a problem with how Eclipse exports the Jar, if no, it sounds like Realms annotation processor isn't running correctly.